# How to use a variable in load()?

Tags: jquery, load

I found this `.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )` in the jQuery documentation. I write this

```
$('#myModal .modal-body').load($(this).attr('href'));
```

then the complete html of the href is loaded. If I write this, it's the same

```
var modalUrl=$(this).attr('href');
$('#myModal.modal-body').load(modalUrl);
```

But when i do

```
$('#myModal.modal-body').load('/cms/myPage_1.html #content');
```

only the part between the #content is loaded. That's what I want. Unfortunately, that doesn't work if I use the variable as a url like

```
var modalUrl=$(this).attr('href');
$('#myModal.modal-body').load('modalUrl #content');
```

or

```
$('#myModal.modal-body').load(modalUrl #content);
```

or

```
$('#myModal.modal-body').load(modalUrl + '#content');
```

Is that even possible? I can't use a fixed url because there are different links on the site

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does it work with `$('#myModal.modal-body').load(modalUrl + ' #content');` -> Space before `#content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this solution is incorrect, why?

```
$('#myModal.modal-body').load('modalUrl #content');
```

Because you explain to the language that this variable is a string, it is very natural for it not to recognize it

---

Second, this solution is incorrect, why?

```
$('#myModal.modal-body').load(modalUrl #content);
```

Because you forgot the + sign, add to this that you did not put id inside a double comma , like this :

```
$('#myModal.modal-body').load(modalUrl + "#content");
```

But even with this reform will not work, why? see three

---

Third, this solution at first glance seems correct, but it is not, why?

```
$('#myModal.modal-body').load(modalUrl + '#content');
```

Because simply the end result in the browser when render the JavaScript file will be like this:

```
$('#myModal.modal-body').load('/cms/myPage_1.html#content');
```

So what is the solution ? see four

---

Fourth, try this solution

You have two solutions here

- First solution

```
$('#myModal.modal-body').load(modalUrl + '' + '#content');
```

Here we make a space between the variable and the id

- Second solution

```
$('#myModal.modal-body').load(`${modalUrl} #content`);
```

Here, we use double commas of the type ``

The advantage of this type of double comma is that it recognizes spaces, unlike primitive double commas.